# im trying to do the reverse vowel challlange from leetcode, code looks good but its not working

Tags: javascript

with input 'hello', output should be 'holle'

heres my code,

```
var reverseVowels = function (s) {
  // change s into array
  // if a, i, u, e, o
  // change that item to 'marked'
  // also put the index of that marked items into another array
  // put the marked items to another array
  // sort that marked items array, then reverse it
  // // im at here right now
  // then put that array inside its original place

  let newString = s.split('');
  let markedItems = [];
  let markedItemsIndex = [];
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
    if (
      newString[i] === 'a' ||
      newString[i] === 'i' ||
      newString[i] === 'u' ||
      newString[i] === 'e' ||
      newString[i] === 'o'
    ) {
      markedItemsIndex.push(i);
      markedItems.push(newString[i]);
      newString[i] = 'marked';
    }
  }

  let reversedMarkedItems = markedItems.reverse();

  for (let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
    if (i === markedItemsIndex[count]) {
      console.log('here');
      newString[i] = reversedMarkedItems[count];
    }
    count++;
  }

  // return [newString, markedItems.reverse(), markedItemsIndex];
  return newString;
};
```

look at the second loop, im checking if the i === markedItemsIndex but my code never goes there, because of that, the 'here' never returns.

i've checked the type of i and type of markedItemsIndex, they're both a number. how can i fix this

Comment: first of all, you should clarify what the challenge actually is ...

Answer (score 1):

You should only increment the `count` once the vowel at that index has been handled, i.e inside the if statement (not on every iteration, which causes a lot of them to be skipped).

```js
if (i === markedItemsIndex[count]) {
    newString[i] = reversedMarkedItems[count];
    count++;
}
```

You also need to handle uppercase vowels as well, which can be checked more easily with a regular expression. Change the `if` statement in the first loop to:

```
if (/[aeiou]/i.test(s[i])) {
    // update markedItems...
}
```

Finally, use `Array#join` with an empty string to get a string as the result.

```js
return newString.join('');
```

Comment: wait WHATT IT WAS THE COUNT XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD, and yes i know that join thing thanks man

Comment: @me-an-ape Happy to help. For your code to pass, you still need one more change to handle uppercase vowels as well. Change the if statement in the first loop checking the vowels to: `if (/[aeiou]/i.test(s[i]))`

Comment: yup, i added those aswell after trying to submit it

Answer (score 0):

`Move the count++` inside the `if`:

```js
var reverseVowels = function (s) {
  let newString = s.split('');
  let markedItems = [];
  let markedItemsIndex = [];
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
    if (
      newString[i] === 'a' ||
      newString[i] === 'i' ||
      newString[i] === 'u' ||
      newString[i] === 'e' ||
      newString[i] === 'o'
    ) {
      markedItemsIndex.push(i);
      markedItems.push(newString[i]);
      newString[i] = 'marked';
    }
  }

  let reversedMarkedItems = markedItems.reverse();

  for (let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
    if (i === markedItemsIndex[count]) {
      newString[i] = reversedMarkedItems[count];
      count++;
    }
  }

  return newString.join(''); // Join the array back into a string
};

console.log(reverseVowels('hello')); // Output: "holle"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array::unshift()` to collect the vowels already in a reversed order:

```js
const reverseVowels = str => {
  const arr = [...str], set = new Set([...'aeiouAEIOU']), vowels =[], indices = [];
  arr.forEach((char,idx)=>set.has(char) && vowels.unshift(char) && indices.push(idx));
  indices.forEach((idx, i) => arr[idx] = vowels[i]);
  return arr.join('');
};

console.log(reverseVowels('hello'));
```